# Angular 2: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically from MockBackend

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular2 and trying to run this [tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial). It uses a `fakeBackendProvide` to simulate backend calls using `MockBackend`.

Logic for fackBackend goes like this:
`export let fakeBackendProvider = {}`

`index.ts` class helps to export the `fackBackendProvider` with one line:
`export * from './fake-backend';`

`app.module.ts` looks like this:

```
providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    AuthenticationService,
    UserService,

    //fake backend providers
    fakeBackendProvider,
    MockBackend,
    BaseRequestOptions
  ],
```

I am getting this error message:
`ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 7:15 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol fakeBackendProvider in /Users/hyadav/Documents/hp-app/src/app/helpers/fake-backend.ts, resolving symbol fakeBackendProvider in /Users/hyadav/Documents/hp-app/src/app/helpers/index.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/hyadav/Documents/hp-app/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/hyadav/Documents/hp-app/src/app/app.module.ts`

No idea what is going wrong.

Rest of the code, can be found here: [Github](https://github.com/himanshuy/hiringplus-ui/tree/master/src/app/helpers)

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11262

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue with the same tutorial. What I did was just create a new function from the lambda expression and then just invoked it inside the useFactory in fakeBackendProvider.

```
export function mockBackEndFactory(backend: MockBackend, options: BaseRequestOptions, realBackend: XHRBackend) { ... }

export let fakeBackendProvider = {
  provide: Http,
  deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions, XHRBackend],
  useFactory: mockBackEndFactory
};
```

Here's the link for fake-backend.ts file I modified: https://github.com/cealmees/Angular2-training/blob/master/src/app/entities/login/helpers/fake-backend.ts

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps me to resolve the same issue. Let me know why your way is right and tutorial way is wrong? ^^

Comment: Tutorial's way isn't wrong. The main problem was Angular 2 version (which was RC4). The tutorial code was written on an older version, and when I tried to compile it through the latest version of Angular Cli (Angular 2 RC5), I faced the error. I just updated that part of the code and that did the magic. :)