# fakeBackendProvider caused webpack compilation fail in latest Angular-cli generated project

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, backend, angular-cli

I'm trying to use `fakeBackendProvider` from git `cornflourblue/angular2-registration-login-example` in latest Angular-cli generated Angular 2 project. The console always printed following error message:

#### Error messages:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 7:17 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol fakeBackendProvider in c:/develop/accaella/aella_manager/src/app/_helpers/fake-backend.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in c:/develop/accaella/aella_manager/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in c:/develop/accaella/aella_manager/src/app/app.module.ts

I cannot find a way to resolve it. Can someone help please?

```
  ng -v

  @angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.0
  node: 7.5.0
  os: win32 x64
  @angular/common: 2.4.8
  @angular/compiler: 2.4.8
  @angular/core: 2.4.8
  @angular/forms: 2.4.8
  @angular/http: 2.4.8
  @angular/platform-browser: 2.4.8
  @angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.8
  @angular/router: 3.4.8
  @angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.0
  @angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.8
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11262

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically from MockBackend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41781781/angular-2-error-encountered-resolving-symbol-values-statically-from-mockbackend)